Is it possible to perform a compile-time check on the length of an initializer list in C++?
I’m working on a linear algebra library in C++, and I have a structure similar to a vector that stores a fixed number of elements. I’ve implemented a constructor that accepts a std::initializer_list<T> to initialize the elements, but I’d like to ensure that the length of the list matches the expected length at compile-time, instead of doing it at runtime.
Here’s the constructor I currently have:
template <nsp_length::length_t L, nsp_concepts::is_numeric T>
vec<L, T>::vec(std::initializer_list<T> init_list) : data_v{std::make_unique<array_type>()}
{
    assert(init_list.size() == L);  // Runtime check
    std::copy(init_list.begin(), init_list.end(), data_v->begin());
}

As you can see, I’m currently using an assert for a runtime check to ensure that the number of elements in the list matches L. However, I’d like to perform this check at compile-time to avoid the runtime overhead and make the code more efficient and safe.
My question is:
Is there a way to perform this length check on the initializer list at compile-time? I’ve considered using static_assert, but I haven’t found a way to do this with std::initializer_list since its size isn’t known at compile-time.
Is there any technique or approach in C++ that would allow me to perform this check at compile-time?

static_assert can be used for compile time checks.

You can do the compile time check if you use vararg template instead of  initializer list.

Since C++14, std::initializer_list::size() is constexpr.   So, if the list is populated at compile time, its size can be checked at compile time - but this won't work for a initializer_list that is populated based on data obtained at run time.   Between C++11 and C++14 it was const, so a compile time check would not be possible.

No need to use an initializer list here, use template<typename T, std::size_t N> void f(const T (&data)[N]). And then you also do not need to use your static_assert (if N always needs to be the same you also do not need N)

If compile-time checking of the initializer list is not possible, my option is to disable the constructor that uses the initializer list and instead use a variadic template approach to initialization.

"to avoid the runtime overhead" -- An assert has no runtime overhead when NDEBUG is defined (often done in release builds). It's still valid to want a compile-time check since that will catch errors earlier. It's just the stated justification that is weak.

"since its size isn’t known at compile-time" -- More precisely, its size isn't known when compiling the constructor.

Parameters are not constexpr (even in consteval function).
You might use sized container instead as C-array:
template <nsp_length::length_t L, nsp_concepts::is_numeric T>
class vec
{
// ...
    vec(const T (&init_list)[L]) : data_v{std::make_unique<array_type>()}
    {
        std::copy(init_list.begin(), init_list.end(), data_v->begin());
    }

    template <nsp_length::length_t L1>
    vec(const T (&init_list)[L1]) = delete; 
};

Demo
It might require extra {..}, and to bypass the default initialization of missing initializer, the deleted other constructor might be used.
